# Retornar a quantidade de datas no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho a tabela que contem o campo data.

```
| Data|
| 2016-06-09   |
| 2016-06-09   |
| 2016-06-09   |
| 2016-06-08   |
| 2016-06-08   |
| 2016-06-05   |
| 2016-06-01   |
```

Quero que retorne mais ou menos assim:

```
| Data | Quantidade |
| 2016-06-09 | 3 |
| 2016-06-08 | 2 |
| 2016-06-05 | 1 |
| 2016-06-01 | 1 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `COUNT` e o `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `Data`, COUNT(`Data`) AS 'Quantidade' FROM sua_tabela
GROUP BY `Data`;
```

Comment: Ah era isso mesmo cara, valeu :D